# Cannot float Custom component to the left of another custom component in Angular JS

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have 2 custom components  and . I want  to appear to the left of the  component in order to make it horizontal scrollable. However even after using several js file and tutorials I am unable to do so. As a last resort I defined a class **floatleft** with the property **float : left;**. But it is still being placed vertically, one component after the other.

Comment: Can you reproduce your error in a demo on jsfiddle.net for example?

Comment: Can I edit the question and post it over here. I am new to Web Development and JFiddle is turning out to be little troublesome now.